# How to replace all undefined values in an array with "-"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, undefined, array-map

I have an array like:

```
var array = [1, 2, undefined, undefined, 7, undefined]
```

and need to replace all `undefined` values with `"-"`. The result should be:

```
var resultArray = [1, 2, "-", "-", 7, "-"]
```

I think there is a simple solution, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: Already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320166/javascript-replace-undefined-with-0?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: is zero a valid value?

Comment: do you have a sparse array?

Comment: yes, zero is a valid value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check for `undefined` and take `'-'`, otherwise the value and use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for getting a new array.

```js
var array = [1, 2, undefined, undefined, 7, undefined],
    result = array.map(v => v === undefined ? '-' : v);
    
console.log(result);
```

For a sparse array, you need to iterate all indices and check the values.

```js
var array = [1, 2, , , 7, ,],
    result = Array.from(array, v => v === undefined ? '-' : v);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var array = [1, 2, undefined, undefined, 7, undefined];
var newArray = array.map(x => x !== undefined ? x : "-");
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `map` the values and return `-` if undefined.

```js
let array = [1, 2, undefined, undefined, 7, undefined]

let result = array.map(o => o !== undefined ? o : '-');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Array.map()

```js
var array = [1, 2, undefined, undefined, 7, undefined];
console.log(array);

var newArray = array.map(function(v) {
  return undefined === v ? '-' : v;
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newArray = array.map(function(val) {
    if (typeof val === 'undefined') {
        return '-';
    }
    return val;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function SampleArray() {
            var Array = [];
            var array = [1, 2, undefined, undefined, 7, undefined];
            for (var i = 0; array.length > i; i++) {
                var Value;
                if (array[i] == undefined) {
                    Value = '-';
                } else {
                    Value = array[i];
                }

                Array.push(Value);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this -

```
array.forEach(function(part,index,Arr){ if(!Arr[index])Arr[index]='-'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use functional programming map function:

```
 let array = [1, 2, undefined, undefined, 7, undefined];

 let array2 = array.map(e => e === undefined ?  e='-' :  e);
```

Comment: the same answer with the done one! why -1? this is a misleading for people searching for real help!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
while((index = array.indexOf(undefined)) > -1){array[index] = "-";}
```

"-"

this will search for the index of the value you are searching for, and replace it with "-"